# Xcode 6.4 Run Script to modify project.pbxproj no longer works

Tags: ios, xcode

Prior to Xcode 6.4, I had a run script that looks like the following:

```
echo "Adding compiler flags"
PROJ_FILE="${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}/project.pbxproj"

STR_SRCH="STTwitterAPIWrapper.m \*/; };"
STR_RPLC="STTwitterAPIWrapper.m \*/; settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = \"-fno-objc-arc\"; }; };"

if grep "${STR_SRCH}" "$PROJ_FILE"
then
sed -i "" "s|${STR_SRCH}|${STR_RPLC}|g" "$PROJ_FILE"
else
exit 0
fi

STR_SRCH="JSONKit.m \*/; };"
STR_RPLC="JSONKit.m \*/; settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = \"-fno-objc-arc\"; }; };"
sed -i "" "s|${STR_SRCH}|${STR_RPLC}|g" "$PROJ_FILE"

STR_SRCH="ZipArchive.mm \*/; };"
STR_RPLC="ZipArchive.mm \*/; settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = \"-fno-objc-arc\"; }; };"
sed -i "" "s|${STR_SRCH}|${STR_RPLC}|g" "$PROJ_FILE"
```

However, after updating to Xcode 6.4, the script doesn't seem to do what's supposed to do. I'm just trying to add the -fno-objc-arc compile flag so that I don't have to do it manually.

Any one else run into this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Open the file, check its content, there might be something really simple like a missing space at "; }". If the file is actually modified with the script but the flag doesn't apply - highlight this piece of information.

Comment: @A-Live thanks for the tip, but I made sure that wasn't the issue just now.

Another thing that I noticed was that I would have another pbxproj file created after I ran my project with something like .!187668!project.pbxproj in my repository. Is that something new in xcode 6.4?

Comment: Never seen a file like that, Xcode might be trying to prevent external modifications. Have you tried to build the target via terminal using xcodebuild with closed Xcode ? Of course even if it worked that might be inconvenient as you'd have to add/remove the script phase manually, still might be useful if you have a large set of files managed this way.